# Installing Ubuntu Server on a SONY VAIO with NO hardware-virtualization

Tags: server, virtualization, vaio, sony

Is there a version of UBUNTU server that can be installed on a laptop (SONY VAIO) with the hardware-virtualization disabled?
It is not possible to enable hardware-virtualization in some VAIO laptops. Hve tried everything, but SONY has disabled this from most of their laptops.
I tried to install UBUNTU Server v 14 but came back with an error related to the fact that the hardware-virtualization was not enabled.
Any ideas?
Thanks very much

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have a SONY VAIO laptop and as you might know, SONY disabled the hardware virtualisation in most of their laptops. I thought that this was the issue as to why I was not able to install UBUNTU. I then, and I suppose it shows my lack of knowledge, realised that the SONY VAIO was running 32bit. I was trying to install the 64bit. I have since been able to install the 32bit server - a bit of a painful process. The thing i am finding now is that the graphics is proving a problem when installing the GUI for the server- a different Q. This one is closed. Thanks again.